# recursively update content

Tags: wp-update-post

**the problem**

I'm trying to translate a wordpress 4.7. But the site was consived in spanish and just now I installed the WPML plugin, now after 5000 post uploaded.

I am using the visual composer and custom fields for all the structure of the content.

for some reason, when I go the english view, all my custom fields didn't appear. That is because when it was created all that field wasnt set to be translated. So I go back to the WPML configurations and configure to copy some of them from spanish to english, and some other set to be translated.

Going back to the post, nothing change, **I have to update my content to see the change implemented**, So I dont want to do that for all my 5000 posts.

**The solution**

There is a [wordpress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) called: wp update post

```
 <?php wp_update_post( $post, $wp_error ); ?>
```

I want to know how can I use that function and update all my 5000 posts?.

Any idea?

Comment: get_posts(), ten loop over them. Not sure what your problem is. Can you try to explain it again?

Comment: I want to update all my posts. In a concrete moment, not when I go into an specific page. Maybe it could run by the cron